# Резервирование канала

Tags: сеть, mikrotik

Есть коммутатор eltex mes2428,в который приходит оптика.

Порты коммутатора будут использоваться под пользователей.
Есть Mikrotik 951,в который приходит резерв,и он же раздаёт Wi-Fi.

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как организовать резервирование в таком случае?

Comment: Вот ни фига не понять. Ну оптика... от кого? от прова, и по ней Инет ходит? а как, кто его маршрутизирует-раздаёт на сеть? Кто провы - и на основном, и на резерве? Рисуй схему, со всеми адресами/масками/шлюзами, будем смотреть.

Comment: Хотя вопрос - ну ни разу не о программировании.

Comment: Оба ISP надо в микротик заводить. по другому никак. Иначе у юзеров на местах маршрутизацию опухнешь прописывать

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev Я тоже сразу так решил,но решил убедиться,чтобы не отметать сразу вариант. DHCP если что не местный. Используется удалённый сервер в другом городе.

Comment: @Akina а какое значение имеют адреса? Оптика от прова. Провайдер - несущественно. В микрот канал от другого прова по меди.
DHCP удалённый,т.е. шлюз не в этом городе находится.
И stackoverflow - это не только про программирование

Comment: *а какое значение имеют адреса?* Как минимум чтобы понимать, что имеется. *Провайдер - несущественно.* Основной и резервный провы - разные? *Оптика от прова. ... DHCP удалённый,т.е. шлюз не в этом помещении находится* Т.е. не напрямую от прова, а есть свой роутер где-то?

Comment: @Akina ядро сети в другом городе.Всё разделено vlan'ами. Медь на данный момент это основной канал,но нужен шире,поэтому завезли от другого провайдера опту. Влан по маршруту уже прокинут. Остался вопрос в одном - можно ли как-то объеденить в тот же LACP,или нереализуемо. Был бы на месте какой-нибудь mikrotik 2011,то вообще бы проблемы не было,но как связать 951 с L2 коммутом - не знаю

Comment: *stackoverflow - это не только про программирование* Найдите иконку со знаком вопроса в правом верхнем углу. Кликните. Перейдите по ссылке "Справка". Внимательно прочитайте текст на картинке во втором абзаце. Потом ниже в разделе "Как задавать вопросы" найдите статью "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?", прочитайте её. Вот если бы вопрос был "Как настроить RouterOS, чтобы..."... а так - всё же оффтоп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, так.

На коммутатор приходит VLAN с Инетом. Допустим, на порт 28.

Включаем в этот VLAN ещё порт 27, и цепляем туда микротик, скажем его порт 2 (к порту 1 подключен резервный пров).

На остальных портах формируем другой VLAN. Туда (скажем, на порт 26) цепляем микротик, порт 3.

На остальные порты коммутатора сажаем клиентов.

Настраиваем микротик на балансировку двух каналов по адресу источника (порты 1 и 2), либо на резервирование канала.

Клиенты теперь будут получать адреса от микротика, а не из головного офиса.

Всё, собсно.

PS. С точки зрения удалённого маршрутизатора, от которого приходит основной Инет, у вас будет ОДИН клиент. Но о-о-очень прожорливый. Ну и логи соединений придётся вести не только им, но и вам. А в случае инцидентов - совмещать их, чтобы найти концы. Кстати, поэтому ещё используйте сервер времени от головного офиса для синхронизации (и заворачивайте туда или на себя все NTP и daylight), а не внешние стратумы.

Comment: А в качестве  холодного резерва микротик может использоваться? Т.е. если через опту трафик не идёт,то использовать канал от микрота.
Использовать его на постоянку собственно нет нужды.

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT А как Вы тогда поняли слова " либо на резервирование канала"?

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT *Т.е. если через опту трафик не идёт* Кстати, это может быть большой проблемой - детектировать, что канал неживой. Особенно если внутри головной организации - несколько хопов. А пингать 8.8.8.8 - стрёмно, как по мне.

Comment: На 28 порт приходит аплинк с VLAN 100. На 27 порту так же задаю 100 VLAN и его во второй порт микрота. На 3 порт микрота и остальные порты коммута раздаю 200.
Так же у меня приходит 1000 VLAN,по которому раздаются адреса от DHCP. Его отдать на все порты тоже нужно будет?

Comment: *аплинк с VLAN 100... приходит 1000 VLAN,по которому раздаются адреса от DHCP* Вот тут откровенно не понял - это вообще как? клиенты у тебя, которые Инет от головной организации кушают, в каком влане-то сидят? Если в 1000-м, чтобы адрес получить - как они в Инет ходют? а если в 100-м, чтобы в Инет ходить - откуда они адреса добывают?

Comment: Да,это что-то меня занесло. Там 1000 уже прокинут.

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста,а как средствами ROS организовать резервирование по следующей схеме? В mikrotik завезли оба аплинка. Один провайдер отдаёт сервисный vlan 101(по нему идёт коннект к dhcp),а другой провайдер по 253. Т.е на самом микроте проблем с переключением активного канала нет,но как это организовать для коммутатора,который включен в порт микрота? На коммутаторе для каждого порта на данный момент присвоен влан 101